# Multer typescript error next(err) is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am developing a MEAN stack app for photo upload and I'm encountering an issue with the follow error. Currently testing this endpoint with postman, everytime I upload an image to the folder the server will stop running and I recieve this error. Any help would be appreciated

```
node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:45make-middleware.js:45
      next(err)
      ^

TypeError: next is not a function
```

In my **post.controller.js**

```js
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './public/uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname + '-' + Date.now() + '-' + getExtension(file));
  },
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5,
  },
});

const getExtension = (file) => {
  // this function gets the filename extension by determining mimetype. To be exanded to support others, for example .jpeg or .tiff
  var res = '';
  if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg') res = '.jpg';
  if (file.mimetype === 'image/png') res = '.png';
  return res;
};

(exports.create = upload.single('imagePath')),
  async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      console.log(req.file, req.body);
      const { title, date } = req.body;
      const imagePath = req.file.path;

      const post = new Posts({
        title,
        date,
        imagePath,
      });

      await post.save();

      return res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        post,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Server Error',
        error: error,
      });
    }
  };
```

And my **posts.route.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const PostsController = require('../controllers/posts.controller');
const Auth = require('../auth/auth');
const multer = require('multer');

const route = express.Router();

route.post('/create', Auth.authenticateJWT, (req, res) => {
  PostsController.create(req, res);
});

route.get('/', Auth.authenticateJWT, (req, res) => {
  PostsController.getAllPosts(req, res);
});

route.get('/:id', Auth.authenticateJWT, (req, res) => {
  PostsController.getPost(req, res);
});

module.exports = route;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define `create` as:

```
exports.create = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.file, req.body);
    const { title, date } = req.body;
    const imagePath = req.file.path;

    const post = new Posts({
      title,
      date,
      imagePath,
    });

    await post.save();

    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      post,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: 'Server Error',
      error: error,
    });
  }
};
```

Export the `upload` variable:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, './public/uploads');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.originalname + '-' + Date.now() + '-' + getExtension(file));
    },
  });
  
exports.upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {
      fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5,
    },
  });
```

And use it as a middleware:

```
route.post('/create', Auth.authenticateJWT, PostsController.upload('imagePath'), PostsController.create);
```